# Unwanted IE9 Open/Save Dialog for mutlipartfile upload

Tags: java, json, internet-explorer, spring-mvc, extjs4

I'm using extjs as a front end to submit form-data to a server.  The form-data includes a multipartfile.  The data is sent as json to a server which returns a response.  Unfortunately, this causes Internet Explorer 9 (my required browser) to prompt "Do you want to open or save uploadClientPgpKey.json from localhost?"  I've already tried to change the contentType in the form, as its basically an ajax request but, I haven't had any success eliminating the aforementioned popup dialog that only appears in IE9 and not in Chrome or Firefox.

Extjs 4.2 code

```
form.submit({
    url: 'services/cp/uploadClientPgpKey.json',
    waitMsg: 'Uploading your PGP Key...',
    //headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/html'},
    success: function(fp, o) {
        this.up('window').close();
        Ext.Msg.alert( 'Processed file "' + o.result.file + '" on the server.');
    },
    failure: function(form, action) {
        obj.up('window').close();
        Ext.Msg.alert('Message', action.response.responseText);
    }   
});
```

Java code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadClientPgpKey", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView uploadPGPKey(@RequestParam("client") String clientKey, 
        @RequestParam("docKey") String docKey, 
        @RequestParam("pgpKey") MultipartFile file)
{
       // lots of code here
}
```